# SPARK : Set a column value based on multiple row conditions

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of the below format:

```
+----+---+-----+------+-----+------+
|AGEF|SEX|F0_34|F35_44|M0_34|M35_44|
+----+---+-----+------+-----+------+
|  30|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  94|  1|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  94|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  94|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  94|  1|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  44|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  66|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  66|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  74|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  74|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  29|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
```

Now based on the values of columns AGEF and SEX I need to assign 1 to corresponding column name. Each column name is self explanatory like F0_34 is female between age 0 to 34 similarly for other case.

Expected output is

```
+----+---+-----+------+-----+------+
|AGEF|SEX|F0_34|F35_44|M0_34|M35_44|
+----+---+-----+------+-----+------+
|  30|  0|    1|     0|    0|     0|
|  94|  1|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  94|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  94|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  94|  1|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  44|  0|    0|     1|    0|     0|
|  66|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  66|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  74|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  74|  0|    0|     0|    0|     0|
|  29|  0|    1|     0|    0|     0|
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically the most efficient approach is to operate directly on SQL expressions. For example:

```scala
def categorize(ageRanges: Seq[(Int, Int)], sexValues: Seq[(Int, String)]) = for {
  (ageL, ageH) <- ageRanges
  (sexV, sexL) <- sexValues
} yield ($"SEX" === sexL && $"AGEF".between(ageL, ageH)).alias(
  s"$sexL-$ageL-$ageH"
)

df.select(
  $"*" +: categorize(Seq((0, 34), (35, 44)), Seq((0, "F"), (1, "M"))): _*
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way is to make a UDF that takes 5 parameters (e.g.: actual_age, actual_sex, target_sex, target_min_age, target_max_age) and returns either 1 or 0. Something like this:

```
val ageRanger = udf[Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int]((age: Int, sex: Int, targetSex: Int, targetMinAge: Int, targetMaxAge: Int) => { 
  if (age >= targetMinAge && age <= targetMaxAge && sex == targetSex) 1 else 0
})
```

Then if you had this `DataFrame`:

```
val df = Seq((30,0),(94,1),(94,0),(44,0)).toDF("AGEF", "SEX")
// +----+---+
// |AGEF|SEX|
// +----+---+
// |  30|  0|
// |  94|  1|
// |  94|  0|
// |  44|  0|
// +----+---+

df.withColumn("F0_34", ageRanger($"AGEF", $"SEX", lit(0), lit(0), lit(34)))
  .withColumn("F35_44", ageRanger($"AGEF", $"SEX", lit(0), lit(35), lit(44)))
  .show
// +----+---+-----+------+
// |AGEF|SEX|F0_34|F35_44|
// +----+---+-----+------+
// |  30|  0|    1|     0|
// |  94|  1|    0|     0|
// |  94|  0|    0|     0|
// |  44|  0|    0|     1|
// +----+---+-----+------+
```

Note that you have to pass values into the `UDF` as `Columns`, so I use `lit(...)` to wrap my `Int` values for the hard-coded values. There could be a slicker way to do that, but it works fine this way.